# How do I implement a 1D integer bin-packing program with excel?

Tags: excel, matlab, lindo

I can't seem to find any resources for this question ANYWHERE that doesn't make it convoluted. Below is an example of one of the questions I need to answer.

Write an integer program for the following instance of bin packing and solve with excel. I can also solve using LINDO or Matlab but I'd rather do with excel.

Six items S = {4,4,4,6,6,6} and bin capacity of 10.

Comment: do you want to solve this particular instance (the optimal packing is obvious)? and why would you use the excel solver if you can use a "real" solver?